# Restlib - Session Time out when running multiple searches

Tags: rest, netsuite

I'm running restlib to query Netsuite. It all work fine when I run it once.

However when I add a second search I get SESSION_TIMED_OUT error message.

Function GetNetsuiteCasesJSON()

```
Dim jsonText As String
Dim jsonObj As Dictionary
Dim jsonRows As Collection
Dim jsonRow As Collection
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim startColumn As Long
Dim i As Long

V_SearchString = "&resultsfrom=0&searchid=XXX&type=customer&join=null&operator=is&fieldname=CUSTENTITYMCCODE&fieldvalue=" & Sheets("INFO").Range("c_customeraccountcode").Value

V_SearchString2 = "&resultsfrom=0&searchid=XXX&type=customer&join=null&operator=is&fieldname=CUSTENTITYMCCODE&fieldvalue=" & Sheets("INFO").Range("c_customeraccountcode").Value

generalQuery "JSON_Netsuite_Cases_Temp", "NetSuite", V_SearchString, , True, "USER", "PASS"

generalQuery "JSON_Netsuite_Cases_Temp", "NetSuite", V_SearchString2, , True, "USER", "PASS"
```

...

Any idea how to perform two searches on Netsuite using Restlib?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing one query, and THEN the other? I'm not familair with Restlib, but NetSuite UI will block the first search if two concurrent requests are made.